# Table names are encoded incorrectly

Tags: postgresql, tomcat, grails

I'm using Grails 2.4.3 on Tomcat 7.0 with PostgreSQL 9.4. I have a domain object called `Iteration`. If I run Grails without Tomcat, the `iteration` table is created. But when I try to run **war** inside Tomcat, **`ıteration`** table is created instead of `iteration`.

I did not set anything in Tomcat configuration files or the Tomcat Service to enable **UTF-8** encoding.

What may cause to this problem to occur?

**EDIT:** Here is my production settings in DataSource.groovy:

```
production {
dataSource {
  dbCreate = ""
  url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db"
  driverClassName = "org.postgresql.Driver"
  username = "postgres"
  password = "password"
  dialect = "net.kaleidos.hibernate.PostgresqlExtensionsDialect"
  logsql = false
  properties {
    jmxEnabled = true
    initialSize = 5
    maxActive = 50
    minIdle = 5
    maxIdle = 25
    maxWait = 10000
    maxAge = 10 * 60000
    timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 1800000
    minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 1800000
    validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
    validationQueryTimeout = 3
    validationInterval = 15000
    testOnBorrow = true
    testWhileIdle = true
    testOnReturn = false
    jdbcInterceptors = "ConnectionState"
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Please post your config file. Without any code, its difficult to say anything.

Comment: Offopic: PostgreSQL 7.4? Are you sure? This version is unsupported for many years and unsafe because of many security issues. Do yourself a favor and upgrade to a recent version, at least 9.2

Comment: I'm sorry about that. I was supposed to be 9.4. Edited it now.

Comment: @Raúl I did't edit any config file but tomcat-users.xml. But I will add my Grails DataSource configuration file ASAP.